# Как сделать "свободную" камеру в three.js

Tags: three.js

Как сделать "свободную" камеру в three.js

Под "свободной" камерой я подразумевают возможность "приближаться" "удаляться" к сцене, а также двигаться по сцене "вверх" "вниз" "вправо" "влево".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции инициализации
Добавить  две строки

```
var trackballControls = initTrackballControls(camera, renderer);
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
```

Comment: А зачем тут clock? Как будто ничто к нему не привязано?